# Laravel/PHP Delete Product from One or More Related Category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have Many to Many Relationship between products and Categories.

1) If a product is deleted its relationship with pivot table is also removed as well.
 I want to delete product from database in case when it does not relates to any other category.

2) If a Category is Deleted its related products will also be deleted. But not those who belongs to any other category.
How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`detach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

```
$user->roles()->detach([1, 2, 3]);
```

And [`on delete cascade`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#foreign-key-constraints):

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: On Delete Cascade is not doing the job with pivot table Or may b i am getting it wrong. One product belong to many categories, i want to delete product from product table only when it does not belong to any other category. 
category_product pivot table.
            $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('products_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('categories_id')
                    ->references('id')->
                    on('categories')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd requirement you can set `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your child(product) table so if you delete any category from Categories table the related products will be deleted from products table.